# Does this series that has terms $1/n$, then terms $1/n (\log n)^2$, then terms $1/n \log n (\log \log n)^3$, etc. converge or diverge?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Define $\log_{(k)}$ to be the logarithm function iterated $k$ times, where $\log_{(0)}$ is the identity function. Consider the series $\sum_n 1/a_n$ where

$$a_n = (\log_{(f(n))} n)^{f(n)+1} \prod_{k=0}^{f(n)-1} \log_{(k)} n$$

where $f(n)$ is the largest non-negative integer such that $\log_{(f(n))} n \geq 1$. So the terms in the series first look like $1/n$ until $n > e$, and then $1/n (\log n)^2$ until $n > e^e$, and then $1/n (\log n) (\log \log n)^3$ until $n > e^{e^e}$, and then $1/n (\log n) (\log \log n) (\log \log \log n)^4$, etc. Does this series converge or diverge? I believe that if we instead defined

$$a_n   =  (\log_{(f(n))} n)^{M} \prod_{k=0}^{f(n)-1} \log_{(k)} n$$

for a fixed power $M > 1$ then the series would diverge. This generalizes a Putnam problem result that the series diverges when $M=1$, and it's surprising that the series diverges for $M > 1$ because it diverges more slowly and also the formula looks much more like convergent series formulas when $M > 1$ instead of $M = 1$. But anyway, I'm actually interested in the case where $M$ grows linearly with the number of iterated logarithms.

Comment: Is is the same as http://mathoverflow.net/questions/111244/series-with-iterated-logs-does-it-converge?

Comment: @sdcvvc In the second series I mentioned, if you put $M = 1$ then I believe it's an equivalent problem. But I believe you even get divergence when $M > 1$, which diverges more slowly and looks much more like the formula for a convergent series. But my main question is what happens when $M$ is not fixed, and instead grows linearly with the number of iterated logarithms.